# Qual a diferença entre [] e [[]] no R?

Tags: r

Simplesmente só utilizei o `[ ]` para definir a posição de um elemento num vetor ou matriz (`[ ]`, `[,]`, `[, ,]`...), mas como funciona o `[[ ]]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vou começar por citar a documentação do R:

> The most important distinction between `[`, `[[` and `$` is that the `[`
>   can select more than one element whereas the other two select a
>   single element.

Tradução Google Translate:

> A distinção mais importante entre `[`, `[[` e `$` é que o `[` pode selecionar
>   mais de um elemento, enquanto os outros dois selecionam um único
>   elemento.

Isto pode-se ver no caso mais simples, o caso de vetores.

```
x <- 1:10

x[4:6]
#[1] 4 5 6

x[[4:6]]
#Error in x[[4:6]] : 
#  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Pode, no entanto, haver outra diferença importante, que passo a explicar.
Quando se extrai só um elemento, o resultado da operação pode ser diferente. Essa diferença não existe no caso de vetores mas existe no caso de listas.

```
identical(x[4], x[[4]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Uma matriz é um vetor com um atributo dimensão, portanto também não há diferença.

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
mat[4]
#[1] 7

mat[[4]]
#[1] 7

identical(mat[4], mat[[4]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Mas no caso de objetos de classe `"list"` já não se pode usar indistintamente `[` ou `[[`. O primeiro extrai uma sub-lista (possivelmente com vários vetores), o segundo um vetor da lista.

```
lst <- list(A = 1:6, B = letters[1:10], C = rnorm(3))

lst[1]
#$A
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

lst[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

identical(lst[1], lst[[1]])
#[1] FALSE
```

E como objetos de class `"data.frame"` são listas, também há uma grande diferença. `[` extrai sub-df's (possivelmente com vários vetores coluna) e `[[` extrai um único vetor.

```
dat <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], 
                  X = 1:10,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat[1]
#   A
#1  a
#2  b
#3  c
#4  d
#5  e
#6  f
#7  g
#8  h
#9  i
#10 j

dat[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Answer (score 16):

Além dos comentários do Rui, eu compartilho a metáfora criada no livro [R para ciência de dados](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#lists-of-condiments):

Imagine que `saleiro` seja:

[image: saleiro]

Então `saleiro[1]`, resulta em:

[image: subset de saleiro]

E, por sua vez, com `saleiro[[1]]` temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, em suma o `[` preserva a forma do objeto exterior, mesmo quando seleciona apenas um objeto, enquanto o `[[` extrai o elemento mesmo, desprezando a "casca" do objeto exterior.

Comment: Não conhecia, boa!